# Complexity of advice language?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, circuit-families, advice-and-nonuniformity

Let $L$ be a language in P/poly.  There is then a deterministic polynomial-time Turing machine $M$ with polynomial-sized advice that decides $L$.  Consider the language $A(M)$ of all advice strings given to $M$ for instances in $L$.

> Is $A(M)$ in P/poly?

**Edit 2:** *For $A(M)$ I am envisaging a specific, unique advice language; the existence of some advice language is guaranteed by the definition of $L$, so for $A(M)$ pick any such language, such as the lexicographically smallest.  Note that $A(M)$ is not necessarily decidable.*

A handwaving (non-)argument for believing this goes something like this.  Every unary language is in P/poly, since a single bit of advice is enough to indicate whether the input is in the language or not.  In some sense advice languages are "sparsifications" of their associated languages; the advice language $A(M)$ contains a sparser representation of some of the information contained in language $L$, tweaked for the specific machine $M$.  <strike>(The advice language could be exponentially sparser, if every string is an instance of the problem, but for sparse languages the advice language may actually be polynomially denser.)</strike>  So it would seem to make sense that sparsifications of languages in P/poly could also be in this class.

Moreover, is there a general relationship between the complexity of $L$ and that of $A(M)$?

These seem like basic questions, so pointers to relevant literature would be appreciated if these are well-known.  A counterexample for the handwaving above would also be useful!

**Edit:** removed a sentence that wasn't even wrong, and based on the comments from Robin and Tsuyoshi, redefined the advice language to depend on $M$ only, as $M$ already depends on $L$.

**Edit 3:** I think Hrushikesh captured the essential problem here, so I am accepting the answer; Tsuyoshi also said essentially the same thing in a comment.  In short, $A(M)$ can be arbitrary.  Any language can be fed as advice to $M$ by waiting until the input instances of the decision problem are large enough for the next piece of advice to be within the polynomial bound.  This also means that I should really have asked the question in terms of a decision problem (where there are both YES and NO instances), not a language, to avoid the case where there are only finitely many YES instances.

Comment: It isn't clear to me that A(L,M) is uniquely specified by L and M. Could you explain that a bit more? (Unrelated: I'd recommend adding the tag advice, and removing ppoly. ppoly looks bad, and is probably too specific to be a tag.)

Comment: The definition of A(L,M) is unclear to me.  Are you viewing a (possibly uncomputable) sequence y_0, y_1, … of advice strings as part of the machine M and defining A(L,M) as the set {y_0, y_1, …} (forgetting which input length they correspond to)?  In that case, I do not expect that there is any relation between L and A(L,M).

Comment: The definition of A(M) is still unclear to me, and the previous comment still applies.  Note that usually the sequence y_0, y_1, … of advice strings is not considered as part of the Turing machine.

Comment: I read revision 4, and would like to point out that an advice is a sequence of strings y_0, y_1, …, not a language.  The set {y_0, y_1, …} of advice strings has little to do with the nature of the advice, because this set “forgets” which i’s each string y_i came from.  The following question occurred to me just now: Is your question really about advice _language_, or is it about the function $1^i \mapsto y_i$ (which might be called advice _function_)?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: In this question I was envisaging the advice language of advice strings, forgetting which input length each string is associated with.  The advice function $\{(i,A(M)(i)) \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ that you suggest, mapping each input length $i$ to the string for the inputs of that length, would probably be an interesting object itself.  However, the advice function wasn't what I had in mind here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Rigorous and probably more correct version at the bottom.*

I don't think so. Consider the case where A(L,M) consists of advice strings of even length. To decide if x is in L, the machine M gets advice yz where y and z are strings of equal length. M discards z and decides membership of x in L only depending on y. Let y be of length n, and let z range over some arbitrary subset S of strings of length n.

In such a case, A(L,M) cannot be in P/Poly since given a string yz, the machine has to test membership of z in S. But since the advice is of length poly(n), the machine cannot work correctly for every S by counting argument.

**Another more rigorous version:**

Let L be the trivial language containing all strings. The machine M ignores its advice and accepts every input. The task is now to construct the set of advice strings A(M) which cannot be in P/Poly subject to the constraint that strings in L of length $n$ get advice of length $O(poly(n))$.

For every length $i$, let $S_i \subseteq {0,1}^i$. Let $S = \cup_i S_i$. Construct a mapping $f: S \rightarrow Z^+$ such that $|s| \leq f(s)$. The mapping just enumerates the strings in $S$ in non-decreasing order of length. The string $s$ serves as advice to M for strings of length $f(s)$.

By choosing $S_i$ to be of superpolynomial description size (can be done because of counting arguments), we get that $S$ (which is also $A(M)$) lies outside P/Poly.

Comment: @Hrushikesh Tila: OK, I think I see what you mean.  Instances of $L$ of length $n$ receive advice of length $2p(n)$; the second part of the advice is from a hard language.  But by a (different) counting argument, isn't it the case that the language of advice is sparse itself, so the part of S that has size $n$ can be described using only polynomially many bits?  At least this is the kind of argument that is intended by the handwaving.  I'd appreciate someone pointing out my error!

Comment: @Andras: What we need is that there are several advice strings of the form yz, yz', yz'', etc. One way to achieve this is with the trivial language L containing all strings. The advice will be of the form y=1^n, and z will range over all strings of length n. The machine will just ignore the advice and accept every string. To get around the "sparsity" problem, we just need a way to map all these advice strings to different integer lengths. This is possible because there exists a (non-uniform) bijection from all finite subsets of integers to the set of integers such that len(advice)=O(poly(n)).

Comment: Argh, can no longer edit the comment. The advice is of the form yz=(1^m)z where m=O(poly(n)) and n is the size of the input.

Comment: @Hrushikesh: Your key point seems to be that there are $2^{N/2}$ different strings in $A(M)$ for every size $N = 2m$.  But this is superpolynomial.  I am intrigued -- could you sketch the bijection you have in mind?

Comment: @Hrushikesh: Perhaps a simpler argument is this: the advice string just has to be _shorter_ than $p(n)$.  So pick any language $K$ that is outside $P/poly$, then feed it to $M$ deciding the trivial language of all strings (as you suggest), in the following way.  Suppose the strings of $K$ are enumerated in increasing size.  If the $i$th string in $K$ is $s_i$, then provide $s_i$ as advice to all inputs with $b$ bits, $2^i \le b \lt 2^{i+1}$.  If $K$ is very sparse, then adjust the interval; it is enough that the function mapping the index in $K$ to size is non-decreasing.

Comment: @Andras: My earlier version lacked rigor. What you say about enumerating strings and creating the mapping seems to be correct. I have written a much simpler more rigorous version at the bottom of my earlier answer. Does it now sound OK?